# Finding Conjugate harmonic of $u = \frac{1}{2} ln(x^2 + y^2)$

Tags: calculus, functions

this is a nice community;

I've been facing a hard time answering this question, a detailed answer would be splendid.

$u = \frac{1}{2} ln(x^2 + y^2)$
find conjugate harmonic, and harmonic function.

Thanks very much

Edit: this is my solution so far
found ∂u∂x, it's square, and ∂u∂y with its square

tried using this equation (F(z)= integration(∂u∂x(z,0)- j∂u∂y(z,0))dz + jc)
....but couldn't get a sensible result of (v)

my results was F(z)=ln(z) +jc = ln(x+jy) + jc ..... as you can see this is not a satisfying solution

Comment: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}$$
$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$$
$$\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}\right)^2=1$$

Comment: It is customary to include your work so far on the problem, and whether or not you have made any progress, to describe the particular difficulty you are having.

Comment: @KennyLau Do you know what a harmonic conjugate is?

Comment: Travis, I edited my question

Comment: Kenny lau, my request is for someone to help me finding the conjugate harmonic, and the function, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u(x,y)=\frac12 \log(x^2+y^2)$ for $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$.  If $v(x,y)$ is the harmonic conjugate of $u(x,y)$, then there is an analytic function $f(z)$ such that $f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$.

If $f(z)$ is analytic, then $u(x,y)$ and $v(x,y)$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann Equations

$$\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial y} \tag 1$$

and

$$\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}=-\frac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial x} \tag 2$$

From $(1)$, we find that

$$\frac{\partial v(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{x}{x^2+y^2}\tag 3$$

Integrating $(3)$ with respect to $y$, we obtain

$$v(x,y)=\arctan2(y,x)+C(x) \tag 4$$

where $C(x)$ is an integration constant with respect to $x$ and $\arctan2(y/x)$ is defined as in [THIS ARTICLE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation).

Applying the Cauchy-Riemann Equation $(2)$ to $(4)$ reveals

$$\frac{\partial u(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}+C'(x)$$

from which we find $C'(x)=0$.

Therefore, setting the integration constant to $0$, the harmonic conjugate of $u(x,y)=\frac12 \log(x^2+y^2)$ is

$$v(x,y)=\arctan2(y,x)$$

Putting it all together,

$$f(z)=\frac12 \log(x^2+y^2)+i\arctan2(y,x)=\log(z)$$

Comment: Thanks very much, I appreciate u taking your time to answer my question @Dr. MV

Comment: You're welcome!  It was my pleasure Sero. -Mark